# Changing character to numeric in data.frame (as.numeric) with thousand separator

Tags: r, csv, numeric, read.csv

I used `read.csv` to import a CSV file with numeric values where the CSV seperator is ";", the decimal seperator is "," and additional the thousend seperator is "."

```
Hist <- read.csv(file = "XXXX", header = T, sep = ";", dec =",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I transformed it in a data.table ...

```
Hist <- data.table(Hist)
```

And it looks like this:

```
  Date        Value
# 2017-11-12  12.456,89
# 2017-11-10  13.234,99
# 2017-11-08  14.123,45
```

Now I want to change the class/format of the column "Value" to numeric since I want to calculate with it. But everything I tried did not worked. For example:

```
Hist[, Value := as.numeric(Value)]
```

is creating the error:

> Warning message:
>   In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are read as strings. In order to convert them to a number remove the thousands separator (.) and then convert the decimal separator (,) to a point.

```
Hist$Value = as.numeric(gsub(",",".",(gsub("\\.","",Hist$Value))))
```

Which is the same as:

```
noPoints = gsub("\\.", "", Hist$Value)
commaToPoint = gsub(",", ".", noPoints)
Hist$Value = as.numeric(commaToPoint)
```

Comment: The solution was the "\\." in gsub. I tried `gsub( ".","," ...)` before.