# Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion while changing to numeric

Tags: r, na

I am reding CSV where one columns is numeric with commas. I am using following option while reading
`Prv_mnth_so <- read.csv("sales office previous month.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
then replacing commas with blank
`Prv_mnth_so1$Lc_Amount <- gsub(",", "", Prv_mnth_so1$Lc_Amount)`
chanfing it to numeric
`Prv_mnth_so3$Lc_Amount <- as.numeric(as.character(Prv_mnth_so3$Lc_Amount))`
but I get following warning
**Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion**
which is creating problem further in doing summary on this column

Comment: Does any of these three posts solve your problem? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598020/converting-character-to-numeric-without-na-coercion-in-r?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247640/changing-character-to-numeric-in-data-frame-as-numeric-with-thousand-separator?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to subset

```
df$a[grep('^\\d+$', df$a, invert = TRUE)]
#[1] "a"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("23", "34", "a", "56"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided an example to give you the exact answer for your data but this warning means there are some values in your data which cannot be converted to numeric.

If you have a very big data and can't manually look into your data what you could do is create a new column with numeric values and then check for values which were turned to `NA`. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("23", "34", "a", "56"))
df$b <- as.numeric(df$a)
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion 
df$a[is.na(df$b)]
#[1] "a"
```

You can then decide what you need to do with these values.